# Apachectl Missing from Apache HTTPD Binary

Tags: centos, httpd

I extracted the httpd...tar.gz from [here](http://mirror.nexcess.net/apache/httpd/), but I don't see `apachectl`.

```
[vagrant@centos48 opt]$ ls
httpd-2.2.23  httpd-2.2.23.tar.gz
[vagrant@centos48 httpd-2.2.23]$ find . -name apachectl
[vagrant@centos48 httpd-2.2.23]$
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you did not build the code. You downloaded the source code. So, you need to build it first to create the binaries and libraries.

Comment: So apachectl doesn't come with the binary? Why?

Comment: @Kevin: It seems to me that you downloaded the source code not the binary. If you downloaded the binary, you should find it already there.

Comment: I downloaded httpd-2.2.23.tar.gz from the above link, and then extracted it using 'tar -zxvf {file.tar.gz}'

Comment: @Kevin: Yes, that's the source code.

Comment: Doh! #Homer. I should've noticed that there wasn't a bin directory. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You have downloaded the source code. `apachectl` is in there, but it's only in source form. You'd have to compile that and install the resulting binary.

But, unless you have a special need, *don't*. Instead,

```
yum install httpd
```

That will get you the compiled package, properly configured with a basic setup, and with all of the tools, including `/usr/sbin/apachectl`.

The version of Apache is slightly older than the one you've downloaded, but it includes backported security patches, and we're way past the era when new minor releases of Apache included very exciting new features, so it's unlikely that you really need it.